# JavaScript Function Arguments in jQuery. Does This Work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`EDIT` Helping people understand the question better

Can you call a argument and then use it in jQuery? I was thinking something like:

```
// Notice the "test" argument in the "foo" function
function foo(test) {
  $("#randomDiv").click(function(){
    $(test).toggle();
  });
}
```

Would something like this work?

Comment: What is it intended to do?

Comment: When you execute a jQuery method on a function call, you need not wrap it inside `document.ready` . Other than that it would work provided you are using the proper selector .. `foo('div') , foo('.class') , foo('#class')` would work

Comment: @AndersonGreen  That's not the point of the question.  I'm asking if it's possible to use a JavaScript function inside jQuery.

Comment: Are you really asking whether you can use "normal" JS function inside of a jQuery method call?

Comment: @Sushanth-- Alrighty, thanks!  quite new to this stuff.  Seemed like a pretty easy question. Even though I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet but thanks for answering anyways.

Comment: @XeroElixir .. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: DID YOU TRY IT? Did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work. But it depends on what you want to achieve.

Your code will be something like a "instant-binder", eg: this code will bind toggling of the element when the document is parsed.

As far as you can bind many listeners for one event, following calls of the same functions will be executed in order.

Answer (score 0):

You should run **foo** at the beginning of the html file. On that way you will be sure that the function **document.ready** would run wait until all the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Nope. It can be even at the end of file because DOMContentLoaded is being executed after all <head> assets are loaded and DOM tree is rendered.